# AntiXSS doesn't sanitize unclosed html tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss

Why are unclosed html tags not sanitized with Microsoft AntiXSS?

```
string untrustedHtml = "<img src=x onmouseover=confirm(foo) y=";
string trustedHtml = AntiXSS.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(untrustedHtml); // returns "<img src=x onmouseover=confirm(foo) y="
```

Closing tags are sanitized:

```
string untrustedHtml = "<img src=x onmouseover=confirm(foo) y=a>";
string trustedHtml = AntiXSS.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(untrustedHtml); // returns ""
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use HTML encoding whenever possible instead of HTML sanitation.
Sanitation should only be used if you actually need to use some HTML but want to remove any unsafe code. 99% of the times you don't need any HTML to be inserted by your users, and eliminating that should be done with encoding.

Having said that, if you still want to perform sanitation, AntiXSS is not the best solution - both because of the example above, and the fact that it also removes totally safe HTML and falsely recognizing it as unsafe, causing AntiXSS sanitizer to be ineffective.
Ajax control toolkit have a better internal sanitizer you can use, but notice that it is less secured because their partly work with black-lists (searching for the dangerous code instead of permitting only safe code).

If you still want to use AntiXSS sanitation, you can just check whether the HTML that was inserted is a valid one before you sent to the sanitizer. You can do it for example with XML document class of some kind as any valid HTML is also a valid XML.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What version of the AntiXss library are you using?

I used version 4.3.0.0 and when I ran this through Encoder.GetSafeHtmlFragment()

and the output gave the following value "<img src=x onmouseover=test(1) y="
as you can see, they automatically encoded the non-HTML values.

Here is the code I used:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var testValue = "<img src=x onmouseover=test(1) y=";
  litFirst.Text = testValue;
  litSecond.Text = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtml(testValue);
  litThird.Text = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(testValue);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script>
    function test(x) {
      alert(x);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      First: <asp:Literal ID="litFirst" runat="server"/>
      <br/>
      Second: <asp:Literal ID="litSecond" runat="server"/>
      <br/>
      Third: <asp:Literal ID="litThird" runat="server"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I also agree with Gil Cohen, in that you really should not allow users to enter HTML.

Along with Gil Cohen, I would recommend that instead of allowing them to enter in HTML directly, do it through an intermediate language like Markup, Textile, Wiki markup to name a few.  This gives the advantage of allowing users to have more control over there output but still does not let them write HTML directly.

There are JavaScript WYSIWYG editors that will output the markup/preview for the user, then allow you to save the markup language for later use (to be converted to HTML during the output procedure, not before you save it to your data-store).